# weird view with core animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation

Here's the code:

```
 UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];



                CGRect imgFrame = imgView.frame;
                imgFrame.size.width = originalImageSize.width;
                imgFrame.size.height = originalImageSize.height;
                imgFrame.origin.x = 110;
                imgFrame.origin.y = 215;
                imgView.frame = imgFrame;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];

                CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
                frame.size.width = SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT;
                [imgView setFrame:frame];
                 [imgView setCenter:CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT/2, (SCREEN_HEIGHT_PORTRAIT)/2)];

 [fullSizeImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Not sure why when the animation starts, it shifts a bit to the right by some far amount of distance. Any idea? Here's the [video](http://www.screenr.com/qZPs)

Comment: Check which view you add imgView to. I'd say that `imgFrame.origin.x = 110;`is causing the issue, check with 0. That's all I can help with this amount of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `setCenter` before `beginAnimations`

```
imgView.center = CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT/2, yYouLike);
```

Your code should look like this:

```
UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

                CGRect imgFrame = imgView.frame;
                imgFrame.size.width = originalImageSize.width;
                imgFrame.size.height = originalImageSize.height;
                imgFrame.origin.x = 110;
                imgFrame.origin.y = 215;
                imgView.frame = imgFrame;

imgView.center = CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT/2, yYouLike);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];

                CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
                frame.size.width = SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT;
                [imgView setFrame:frame];
                 [imgView setCenter:CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT/2, (SCREEN_HEIGHT_PORTRAIT)/2)];

 [fullSizeImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Then, if your target is iOS 4.0 or later, it is better to use block-based animation methods, like written here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html